# Issue in calling my detailviewcontroller in splitviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

In my app, in splitViewController, in the left tableview, am listing my contacts. On clicking a contact, i want to pass it's contact id to detailViewController. and in the viewDidLoad method of detailViewController am calling a method that hits webservice and pulls the contact details of that contact id and displays them in the detailViewController. This is the logic. But i have problem in calling the detailViewController on the click of tableView. Once i click on the tableview, the ViewDidLoad method of DetailViewController is not called(i have NSlog in ViewDidLoad of detailPage which is not printed)

I have attached the code of rootViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.


if([serachBar.text isEqualToString:@""] || serachBar.text == nil)
{
    NSString *ContactIdStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[objectsForCharacters objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    NSArray *afterSeprate = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    afterSeprate = [ContactIdStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    //NSString *cellText = [afterSeprate objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *detailText = [afterSeprate objectAtIndex:1];

    appdelegate.contactId=[NSString stringWithString:detailText];

}
else
{
    serachBar.text = nil;
    NSString *ContactIdStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSArray *afterSeprate = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    afterSeprate = [ContactIdStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    //NSString *cellText = [afterSeprate objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *detailText = [afterSeprate objectAtIndex:1];

    appdelegate.contactId=[NSString stringWithString:detailText];

}


// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

detailViewController = [[DetailView_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView_iPad" bundle:nil];

 [detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


//self.detailViewController.navigationController


[ContactTableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call a separate instance of `DetailViewController` on every click on tableview on `MasterViewController`.
You need to create a `delegate` for this purpose.
This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial) will help you. Although it uses storyboard but the delegate part can be used by you as well.

Also have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) link to learn more about delegation in iOS.